# How to translate the report accessibility tests axe-core in Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

With this code, I have a report accessibility test in Json :

```
        AxeBuilder axeBuilder = new AxeBuilder();
        try {
            Results axeResults = axeBuilder.analyze(driver);
            ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
            String jsonReport = writer.writeValueAsString(axeResults);
            assertTrue(jsonReport, axeResults.violationFree());
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // Do something with the error
        }
```

I use this dependancy :

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.deque.html.axe-core</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

1. How to have this report in french ? Or how to translate this report ?
2. how to a have the link with the RGAA rules wiht WCAG rules ?

Thanks